# Catel MVVM: How to pass data between windows

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

Hi all I am struggling with the process of sending data between view models in Catel MVVM model. I have a button which on click I want to open a new window and send some data (object) to the newly opened window. However I am unable to solve this by myself so can you help me out?

In my first View Model I have:

```
private readonly IShowStopInfo stopInfo;

//Main constructor of the class
public StopViewModel(IGrtrService grtrService, IShowStopInfo stopInfo)
{
    this.stopInfo = stopInfo;

    Argument.IsNotNull(() => grtrService);
    _grtrService = grtrService;

    AllStops = _grtrService.LoadStop();
    Stop_Line = _grtrService.LoadLines();

    ShowSelectedValue = new Command(OnStopsInfo);
}
public Command ShowSelectedValue { get; private set; }

private void OnStopsInfo()
{
    stopInfo.ShowStopInfo();
}
//Getting Selected Stop from the list
public Stop SelectedStop
{
    get { return GetValue<Stop>(SelectedStopProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedStopProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly PropertyData SelectedStopProperty =  RegisterProperty("SelectedStop", typeof(Stop));
```

In my case I want to send the result from the method "SelectedStop" how can I do that?

Comment: please make sure to mark answers to previous questions such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280047/mvvm-eventtocommand-not-found

Comment: how does this answer my question?

Comment: it helps keeping people motivated to answer your questions, so in that way it definitely helps ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the "[Getting started with WPF](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Getting+started+with+WPF)" section of Catel. It will guide you through creating a first application with all the basics. One of the basics is showing a window with a context.

You can find a very detailed explanation (with screenshots, etc) [here](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Creating+the+view+models#Creatingtheviewmodels-CreatingthePersonViewModel).

Basically you must use the first parameter of the window view model as model injection (in the example it's the Person model).

Then check out the "[hooking up everything together](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Hooking+up+everything+together#Hookingupeverythingtogether-Addingthecommands.1)" part, especially the commands (where the IUIVisualizerService is used to create a window with the currently selected person or family).

For example, the detail vm would look like this:

```
public class MyStopDetailsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MyStopDetailsViewModel(Stop myStop, IMessageService messageService, IPleaseWaitService pleaseWaitService)
    {
         // Here is the context with the injected Stop parameter. Note that I have
         // also injected several other services to show how you can use the combination
    }
}
```

You can call this (as already shown in the example) as follows:

```
var typeFactory = this.GetTypeFactory();
var stopDetailsViewModel = typeFactory.CreateInstanceWithParametersAndAutoCompletion<MyStopDetailsViewModel>(SelecteedStop);
_uiVisualizerService.ShowDialog(stopDetailsViewModel );
```

Comment: hmmm but in my case public Stop SelectedStop is a constructor how can I pass its value?

Comment: public class SelectedStopViewModel
{
    public SelectedStopViewModel(Stop stopModel, IAnotherDependency anotherDependency)
{
    // here is your context
}
}